# enable email notification task list sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, email, task-list

when I try to enable email notification from advanced settings i could not find it and i search about this problem and i find some powershell script to enable it but it's not working can you give me any advice
here is the powershell script

```
$site=Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint2013/"
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks")
if($list -ne $null)
{
   $list.EnableAssignToEmail =$true
   $list.Update()
}
```

Comment: Are you using Default task list template? can you add screen shot of your task list?

Comment: Yes it's the default task , i try to create another same issue

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong in Outgoing email configuration in your environment. Can you validate it by creating same workflow in any list where you can send any email to any person and check whether email is being sent or not

Comment: thanks for your reponse , the Outgoing email configuration is working fine and i find the soluation but it will set all task list to send email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : i find one soluation here [Enable email notifications for Tasks list in SharePoint 2013](https://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/04/26/enable-email-notifications-for-tasks-list-in-sharepoint-2013/) to update all task list to send email notification so if it's not a problem for you go ahead !

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
$webApplicationURL = “https://Your Site.com/”
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $webApplicationURL

if($webApp -ne $null)
{
Write-Host “Web Application : ” + $webApp.Name

foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
{
if($siteColl -ne $null)
{
Write-Host “Site Collection : ” + $siteColl.Url
foreach($subWeb in $siteColl.AllWebs)
{
if($subWeb -ne $null)
{
#Print each Subsite
#Write-Host $subWeb.Url
Write-Host “Site: ” + $subWeb

$site=Get-SPWeb $subWeb.Url
# $web=$site.OpenWeb()
$lists=$site.Lists
if($lists -ne $null)
{

foreach ($list in $lists)
{
if ($list.BaseTemplate -like “Task*”)
{
write-host “Attempting to update: ” + $list.title
$list.EnableAssignToEmail =$true
$list.Update()
}
}
}

$subWeb.Dispose()
}
else
{
Echo $subWeb “does not exist”
}
}
$siteColl.Dispose()
}
else
{
Echo $siteColl “does not exist”
}
}
} else
{ Echo $webApplicationURL “does not exist, check the WebApplication             name”
}Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Echo Finish
});
```